# If I want to manipulate the control points in a path by touching the path, would it be better to use uibezierpath or core graphics?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I want to draw a path and then change it's shape by touching the control points of the path, would it be better to use uibezierpath or core graphics for this purpose and why? I want to get access to the path after im done with modifying it's shape. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to keep the control points in your own data structure, because neither `UIBezierPath` nor `CGPath` provides a convenient way to get at or modify the existing control points of the path.

That said, it's generally easier to use the UIKit drawing API if it covers your needs, so you'll want to convert your data structure to a `UIBezierPath` to draw it each time the user makes a change.